# Force a flexbox element to scroll in cross-axis after matching other element's size

Tags: css, flexbox

There are a few questions that are very similar but after going through I'm pretty sure nothing covers this exact question. Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236336/css-flexbox-shrink-along-cross-axis-and-show-scrollbar) but I would like a flex element rather than a static-size picture.

Using flexbox I want to be able to have a single element match the height (cross-axis) of all other elements, and present a scroll if the content in that element would overflow, rather than growing the height of the container.

I have set up a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0xwwja3/2/) to show what I mean.

Essentially I would like the blue section to collapse and present a scrollbar if it would go extend further down than the red, rather than extending the flexbox vertically.

I have tried a few things and the closest I can get is:

Styling the ".element2" { min-height:0; height:0; } and ".body" { overflow-y:auto; }

which [doesn't scroll](https://jsfiddle.net/b0xwwja3/3/) but has the first element of the correct size.

Any help would be appreciated, and I'm not wed to using flexbox if there is an easier solution.

First fiddle code:

```css
.container{
  display:inline-flex;
}

.element1{
  background-color:red;
}

.element2{
  min-width:180px;
}

.title{
  background-color:green;
}

.body{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element1">
    I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT. I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT. I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT. I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT. I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT. 
  </div>
  <div class="element2">
    <div class="title">
      v Needs scrollbar v
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      Scroll Element <br/>
      Scroll Element <br/>
      Scroll Element <br/>
      Scroll Element <br/>
      Scroll Element <br/>
      Scroll Element <br/>
      Scroll Element <br/>
      Scroll Element <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make the right column `position: relative` with `overflow-y: auto` to scroll when needed
- Make the right column's children `position: absolute` and position appropriately with `top`, `left` and `right`.

The children will no longer take up height, allowing the box to freely grow and shrink in height.

#### Example 1 - Title scrolls

A `min-height` is probably a good idea for the right column.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.element1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.element2 {
  min-width: 180px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.element2 > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.element2 .body {
  top: 1em;
}
.title {
  background-color: green;
}
.body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element1">
    I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT. I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT. I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT. I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT.
    I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT.
  </div>
  <div class="element2">
    <div class="title">
      v Needs scrollbar v
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      Scroll Element
      <br/>Scroll Element
      <br/>Scroll Element
      <br/>Scroll Element
      <br/>Scroll Element
      <br/>Scroll Element
      <br/>Scroll Element
      <br/>Scroll Element
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Example 2 - Title is fixed

We can fix the title in place by placing `overflow-y: auto` and `position: absolute` on the `.body` element. We restrict its height with `bottom: 0` which stretches it to the bottom of its parent (`.element2`)

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.element1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.element2 {
  min-width: 180px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.element2 .body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.title {
  background-color: green;
}
.body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element1">
    I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT. I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT. I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT. I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT.
    I WANT THIS ELEMENT TO CONTROL THE HEIGHT OF THE OTHER ELEMENT.
  </div>
  <div class="element2">
    <div class="title">
      v Needs scrollbar v
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      Scroll Element
      <br/>Scroll Element 1
      <br/>Scroll Element 2
      <br/>Scroll Element 3
      <br/>Scroll Element 4
      <br/>Scroll Element 5
      <br/>Scroll Element 6
      <br/>Scroll Element 7
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is quite simple and usable, thank you! I had initially wanted only the blue section to scroll, and the green to remain static, but this solution works for the project I'm working on.

Comment: @WilliamP - I have also added another example where the title is fixed and doesn't scroll :) If this answer solved your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Comment: Done, this is exactly the behavior I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of the "red" box, just create a `max-height` for the "blue" box and use `overflow-y: scroll`.